# changing the name of sitemap Yoast

Tags: wordpress, seo, sitemap, google-search-console

i am currently using Yoast SEO wordpress plugin, and the sitemap was saved as sitemap_index.xml but would like it to be sitemap.xml, how do i change this?
also anyone have any suggestions with SEO work as im new to it all!

KR

Comment: may i ask what benefit you or anyone get by renaming this.

Comment: was told by my developer its good SEO practice and google will recognize only recognize sitemap.xml, but i get the feeling he was cross i figured to out how to do it without paying him and was lying so i thought id ask u guys

Comment: he was telling lie, i used the same xml file (generated by Yoast SEO plugin ) and successfully added them to Google Webmasters, without a single issue.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to add your sitemap in your `robots.txt` file. For example, add the following line:

```
Sitemap: http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

This is a good solution for all search engines.